# Why doesn't Meteor update the following input on input event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have a `Document` collection with forms that save on `input`:

**document_form.html:**

```
<template name="documentForm">
  <form class="form" role="form">
    <input name="title" type="text" value="{{title}}">
  </form>
</template>
```

**document_form.js:**

```
Template.documentForm.events({
  "input input": function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    currentDocumentId = this._id;

    setTimeout(function() {
      Documents.update(currentDocumentId, {
        $set: {
          title: $(e.target).find('[name=title]').val()
        }
      });
    }, 3000);
  }
});
```

As you can see the `Document` document should update three seconds after input.

What I see instead is my new input for three seconds and then the old one comes back (the old input is being reverted).

So, say, I have a `Document` called `Untitled`. I'll type in the input `AnotherTitle` and then after 3 seconds the input will revert to `Untitled`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: A guess: Minimongo updates the document on the client, but the server rejects the update, and then Minimongo reverts the changes, causing the old title is being used in the template. So, are you sure the update is accepted on the server?

Comment: @Peppe L-G How can I make sure of that? I haven't removed `autopublish` so I don't have anything that could be disrupting the update.

Comment: It's the `insecure` package that allows all writes by default, not the `autopublish` package. But if you execute `Document.update("some-id-of-one-of-your-documents", {$set: {title: "A new title"}})` in the console, you should see some exception or similar if it doesn't work.

Comment: Another way is to check your javascript console when you edit it, its likely it'll throw an Access Denied error with that @PeppeL-G is saying

Comment: By any chance did you fork my sample on MeteorPad? I overwrote it by accident. If you did, can you please share the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you shouldn't use `find('[name=title]')`.
`find()` is used to get the descendants of an element. Here, you are targeting to the input field so it would be enough to use:
`title: $(e.currentTarget).val()`

Hope you find it useful!

Answer (score 1):

To be sure its not the allow/deny

```
   //client.js
    Template.documentForm.events({
      "input input": function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
        currentDocumentId = this._id;
        setTimeout(function() {
        Meteor.call('updateCurrentDocumentId', {
        $set: {
          title: $(e.target).find('[name=title]').val()
        }
      });
    }, 3000);
  }
});

//server.js

    Meteor.methods({
      updateCurrentDocumentId:function(id,item){
           Documents.update(id,item);
        }
     })
```

With this we avoid, the allow/deny.